How to speed up DynamicModule when storing large intermediate results?
I'm building a small gui to explore a large data set.  But, it's very slow if I store intermediate results.  When I don't store intermediate results, the speed is acceptable.
Here's how to reproduce the problem:

Create a large number of associations:

    generateRandomString[] := 
      StringJoin[RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"], 10]];
    
    list = Table[<|"name" -> generateRandomString[], 
        "text" -> generateRandomString[]|>, {1000000}];


We'll be finding elements in these associations that have text matches, using this function:

    matchValueString = Function[{keyName, stringToMatch, list}
       , Select[list, StringContainsQ[keyName /. #, stringToMatch] &]];

Now this function is pretty fast:
  Timing[matchValueString["text", "t", list] // Length]

returns in under a second on my machine.
Now, to incorporate all this in a DynamicModule, I did the following:
DynamicModule[{name, text, foundList}
 , name = ""; text = ""
 ; Grid[{
   {"Name:", InputField[Dynamic[name], String, ContinuousAction -> True]}
   , {"Text:", InputField[Dynamic[text], String, ContinuousAction -> True]}
   , {"Results: ", 
    Dynamic[Length[
      foundList = 
       matchValueString["text", text, 
        matchValueString["name", name, list]]]]}
   , {"Results:", Dynamic[Map[#["name"] &, Take[foundList, UpTo[10]]]]}
   }
  
  ]]

This takes over 40 seconds to execute on my machine.  When typing in values into "Name" or "text" the size of "foundList" significantly impacts the speed.  (Although, in the Timing above, the size of the foundList does not.)  When typing the first single character into Name, the DynamicModule takes several seconds to run.
If, I drop the intermediate result, I get a DynamicModule that's pretty snappy.  The issue is, for my output in my "real" GUI, I need to perform a large number of different computations on "foundList" and as such, for clarity of code, having the intermediate result is really helpful.  Here's the snappy version:
DynamicModule[{name, text}
 , name = ""; text = ""
 ; Grid[{
   {"Name:", InputField[Dynamic[name], String, ContinuousAction -> True]}
   , {"Text:", InputField[Dynamic[text], String, ContinuousAction -> True]}
   , {"Results: ", Dynamic[Length[
      matchValueString["text", text, 
       matchValueString["name", name, list]]]]}
   }
  
  ]]

Are there ways to speed up this code that I'm missing?
I'm using Mathematica 14.0  But can update/upgrade if necessary.

Related question a few days ago: Should large data be localized in DynamicModule, and why does wrapping Module around it cause syntax warnings?

Even though foundList is not ever directly displayed or used anywhere, the kernel still sends the whole list to the front-end at each update, which causes the lag you are seeing. You can observe this behind the scenes by using LinkSnooper.
What you have to avoid is sending your foundList between the kernel and the front-end, and keep it only in the kernel. Do all the calculations and proceessing outside DynamicModule, and bring back only the final results. Here is an example (following Kuba's answer):
processEverything[text_, name_] := 
 Module[{foundList, foundListLength, topResults},
  foundList = matchValueString["text", text, matchValueString["name", name, list]];
  topResults = Map[#["name"] &, Take[foundList, UpTo[10]]];
  foundListLength = Length[foundList];
  {foundListLength, topResults}
  ]

DynamicModule[{name, text, updateFunction, foundListLength, topResults},
 name = ""; text = "";
 Grid[{
   {"Name:", InputField[Dynamic[name, {Automatic, updateFunction}], String, 
     ContinuousAction -> True]}, 
   {"Text:", InputField[Dynamic[text, {Automatic, updateFunction}], String, 
     ContinuousAction -> True]}, 
   {"Results: ", Dynamic[foundListLength]}, 
   {"Results:", Dynamic[topResults]}}
  ],
 Initialization :> (
   updateFunction[___] := (
     {foundListLength, topResults} = processEverything[text, name];
     );
   updateFunction[];
   )
 ]


Just keep in mind that a DynamicModule persists beyond a kernel session and reinstantiates itself when it's copy-pasted as well as all the trouble that could entail.

Ref 80323: "Module variables should never appear inside Dynamics or Manipulates internal to that Module." (orig. source)

@MichaelE2, thanks for bringing this to my attention. I have now changed my answer completely, since my previous attempt was not a good advice. Of course I'm looking forward to your assessment again :)

You're welcome. The OP's use-case is not clear to me. Your code looks better now. If I were going to use this code repeatedly, I'd want the initialization to check list and autoload it when needed. The initialization should also probably define processEverything[]. I think this would make the module self-contained, but I would test myself, if I were the OP.

This works pretty reasonably well.  @MichaelE2, I assume the use case you're not clear on, is how in the real application the data for "list" is generated?  If you think that significantly influences the issue, please let me know, as I don't see how that's relevant to the primary issue of slow performance of dynamic.  Thanks for the most excellent answer.

@John I'm not clear on when the dynamic module will be instantiated. Site users' understandings of instantiation vary widely. If you delete the output every time you're done and evaluate the code every time you start up, then something as simple as Domen's first answer is probably good enough. But if you don't delete the output every time and you're adapting this for a more complicated application, then some bullet-proofing is probably needed. It's hard to decide what's an unnecessary complication and what's needed protection without an understanding of the usage of the module in practice.

@MichaelE2, that's an excellent observation.  This is a pretty trivial application.  Basically all the code is just in this little GUI.  There's not a big complex application.  I did a bunch of testing today on this, and Domen's answer is working just great, and is pretty easy to scale in the ways I need it to scale.
